# Im trying to update database record using update() laravel

Tags: php, laravel

**Controller:**

```
public function updateTeachers(Request $request, User $teachers){
  $validated = $request->validate([
      "name" => ['required'],
      "email" => ['required'],

  ]);

  $teachers->update($validated);

  return back()->with('information-message', 'Data was successfully updated');
```

}

**View:**

```
<form action="/teacher/{{ $dataTeacher->id }}" method="POST" class="bg-white divide-y dark:divide-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-80 px-4 py-3">
      @method('PUT')
      @csrf
      <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
        <div class="w-full px-3">
          <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
            Name
          </label>
          <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ $dataTeacher->name }}" class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" required>
          
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6">
        <div class="w-full px-3">
          <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-password">
            Email
          </label>
          <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ $dataTeacher->email}}" class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500" required>
      
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="text-white bg-blue-700 hover:bg-blue-800 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5   text-center dark:bg-blue-600 dark:hover:bg-blue-700 dark:focus:ring-blue-800">Push</button>
```

**Route:**

```
Route::put('/teacher/{teacher}', [UserController::class, 'updateTeachers']);
```

Is my update code wrong? It's not working it shows only the **information-message**.

Any way to use the update in laravel?

Comment: Ensure the `$fillable` array is set correctly on your Eloquent model.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between route-model binding variable.

**Cause**

The spelling of variable `$teachers` in controller

```
public function updateTeachers(Request $request, User $teachers) {
   ...
}
```

must match the variable `{teacher}` in route.

```
Route::put('/teacher/{teacher}', [UserController::class, 'updateTeachers']);
```

**Fix**

Either both should be singular or both plural. Laravel convention is to keep it singular. Meaning `{teacher}` is correct in route.

To fix, update variable `$teachers` to `$teacher` in controller method definition. This will fix the problem.

**Note**

My understanding is `name` and `email` are in `$fillable` protected array on `User` model.

```
// app/Models/User.php

protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', ...];
```